# How to initialize ModelMultipleChoiceField from table value?

Tags: django, django-forms

Django 1.4, I am using ModelMultipleChoiceField in an admin page, so I have added to form like below

```
class EmailBatchForm(ModelForm):
   proposals = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False,\
      widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("proposals", is_stacked=False),\
      queryset=BuyRequest.objects.all())

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

It saves to table with value string like 
  "[, ]"

When I edit the record, I need the ModelMultipleChoiceField populated with the save value, it seems I have to manually set it

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EmailBatchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.initial['proposals'] = BuyRequest.objects.filter(...)
```

I have to give it a queryset, but how do I filter the queryset with the saved string value?

The saved string value is just pair of Object type and object name, seems it cannot unique identify each record, I think a comma separated object key is better, but how can I set so it saves like that?

Thanks

Comment: What is this widget `FilteredSelectMultiple`? Is it coded by yourself or a 3rd party?

Comment: It is a build in one.
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

Comment: Hmm, this is offtopic, but give a try to jquery.select2. I know the admin widget is nice.